# Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I've had problem with rails for a long time now, I tried a lot of the answers for similar problems I found here but while some of them were effective with some errors I have been stuck and could not solve this, I tried most solutions for similar questions I found and finally decided to ask myself, this error happens only when starting the server for this particular project, while the server launches normally for a new empty rails project:

```
$ rails server
/Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in    `require': dlopen(/Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
from /Users/celorisoli/logbook/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/celorisoli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Most answers help a problem that states 'image not found', however the error here is the following:

```
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
```

Comment: http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/ helpful?

Comment: I have tried that before for both instances of install_name on the link it returns:

    install_name_tool: can't open file: /usr/local/bin/search (No such file or directory)


or


    install_name_tool: can't open file: /usr/local/bin/indexer (No such file or directory)

Comment: The links now http://c.kat.pe/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/ ... I suggest installing MySQL through homebrew.

Comment: i'm getting this errors as well. did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 3):

You need to find where libmysqlclient.18.dylib actually is on your machine and update the bundle with the correct path.

For example, my error message was:

> /Users/rbotzer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require':
>   dlopen(/Users/rbotzer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle,
>   9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)

I located libmysqlclient.18.dylib at /usr/local/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Now to update the bundle:

> sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>   /usr/local/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
>   ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mysql-2.9.1/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle

That fixed the problem for me.